# Access Join Relationships

Tags: ms-access, outer-join, relationships

Good Morning, 
I have an access database where I will be tracking proposals that come into our office. The  (usual) first step to a proposal is a letter of intent (LOI) and then there'd be a one to one relationship linking the LOI ID to Proposal ID. One LOI to one proposal.

But, prior to 2009, our office didn't have LOIs so I'd need the ability to add proposals that do not have a corresponding LOI to the proposals table. I'm trying to construct a Right Outer Join but that doesn't seem to help. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Good evening :) , please add the SQL of the query you have tried to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It's not queries I'm having difficulties with though. It's the relationships themselves

Comment: Well, what exactly is the problem? *"but that doesn't seem to help"* is a little vague.

Comment: I'd need the ability to add proposals that do not have a corresponding LOI to the proposals table. I'm trying to construct a Right Outer Join but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you  are trying to construct a right outer join.  Its a LEFT JOIN that you want.

Comment: That's a fair point and it is likely that I may be getting them mixed up. When I try a right or left join, I still can't add a proposal without a corresponding LOI. :-/

Comment: How are you generating the primary keys for the two tables.  if you take proposal table left join loi table, then you need to match the primary keys, but only the proposal table can have an autonumber as you have to allocate the LOI to match.  But if your normal business process is to create the LOI entry first you are stuck.  If you are creating them manually it might be OK